# Handled double Click event selecting snap svg text

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, dom-events, snap.svg

I'm using `snapsvg` for my project in which I'm handling `dblclick` event for some purpose (say browser window alert). That is when I chick on svg canvas, alert pops up. The problem is that when I click on canvas, some text on canvas also gets selected, which I don't want it to happen.

Any ideas how to get rid of it?

Here is the [code on JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kapil_sarwat/7L0feko2/) to reproduce the same problem. Click anywhere on canvas and observe the text as it gets selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [Alexandr Kiseloy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5639448/alexandr-kiseloy), I have added `#Canvas { user-select: none; }` in css file and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add dbl click event handler only to group

```js
let canvas = Snap('#Canvas');
let g1 =canvas.g();
g1.add(canvas.rect(10,10,50,50).attr({fill:'#9abdce'}));
g1.add(canvas.text(15,25,"Rect1"));

g1.dblclick((function(event){
    alert("Using double click for something else");
}))
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested but the problem is still there (https://jsfiddle.net/kapil_sarwat/7L0feko2/3/), i.e. when I click on canvas, text is selected, I want to get rid of that selection at all.

Comment: Add css property to canvas #Canvas { user-select: none; }

Comment: yes, it solved my problem. Thanks. Good day.